# npm tslint don't give error

Tags: npm, tslint

Hey all got a issue with [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) and [tslint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tslint) I was hoping you could help me with.
Ok here comes my situation and code:

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint -c tslint.json 'src/app/**/*.ts'",
    "pretest": "npm run lint ",
    "test": "echo 'No test are made'",
...
  },
```

When I run command `npm test` this is the output:

**input terminal**

```
$ npm test
```

**output terminal**

```
> keoom@1.0.0 pretest c:\Users\Hjorth\Documents\github\keoom-angular
> npm run lint


> keoom@1.0.0 lint c:\Users\Hjorth\Documents\github\keoom-angular
> tslint -c tslint.json 'src/app/**/*.ts'


> keoom@1.0.0 test c:\Users\Hjorth\Documents\github\keoom-angular
> echo 'No test are made'

'No test are made'
```

If I **only** run command `tslint -c tslint.json 'src/app/**/*.ts'` I on the other hand see the linting error.

**input terminal**

```
$ tslint -c tslint.json 'src/app/**/*.ts'
```

**output terminal**

```
src/app/app.component.ts[1, 27]: " should be '
```

So as you can see there is a linting error in my code, but if I am not running the script directly It will not show. What I am expecting is this:

When I run `npm test` the script `pretest` will run, and that script will run the script `lint`, it will then exit with `exit 0` before `test` script is run as it will find the linting error.

Anyone that can be of assistance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's the quotes around the file spec in the `tslint` command that are the problem:

```
"lint": "tslint -c tslint.json 'src/app/**/*.ts'"
                               ^               ^
```

If you remove those, you should see the expected error reported by `tslint`.

Comment: I will check when I get home from work, but is it possible to get a explanation why the single quotes should silence the output? and only silence it when I am running the script from another script?

Comment: Because when you run it via the terminal, the shell is interpreting what's inside the quotes and is passing the enclosed string as the file spec argument to `tslint`. However, when NPM is interpreting the `script` command, that's not happening and `tslint` receives a file spec that includes the quotes - and doesn't match anything.

Comment: It now brakes horrible at the tslint error, thanks :)